# run update or insert query after select query mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, post, insert-query

i have spend more than 24 hours trying to run update or insert query after select query but select query done and update or insert query never done when submite "displayid"

code##

```
if($_POST["displayid"]==TRUE) {

    $sqlid = "SELECT * FROM doc1 WHERE idnum ='$pidnum' AND stats='$ok'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlid);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
         $sqlup = "UPDATE doc1 SET  m_phone='$pmphone', seen='$dataseen' WHERE  idnum ='$pidnum'";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sqlup);
        $found=1;
    }
    else {
        $found=0;
        $sqlfail="INSERT INTO fail(fname,lname,tname,funame,idnum,m_phone,reg_date) VALUES('$pfname','$plname','$ptname','$pfuname','$pidnum','$pm_phone','$todaydate')";
        $conn->query($sqlfail);
    }

}
```

Comment: try `if(isset($_POST["displayid"]))` instead of `if($_POST["displayid"]==TRUE)`. Learn about prepared statments to prevent SQL injection

Comment: try this $conn->query($sqlfail); to this mysqli_query($conn,$sqlfail);

Comment: i use connection as $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you update query is wrong.
for checking errors please add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Updated code

```
if ($_POST["displayid"] == TRUE) {

    $sqlid = "SELECT * FROM doc1 WHERE idnum ='$pidnum' AND stats='$ok'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlid);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $sqlup = "UPDATE doc1 SET  m_phone='$pm_phone', seen='$dataseen' WHERE  idnum ='$pidnum'";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sqlup);
        $found = 1;
    } else {
        $found = 0;
        $sqlfail = "INSERT INTO fail(fname,lname,tname,funame,idnum,m_phone,reg_date)
VALUES ('$pfname','$plname','$ptname','$pfuname','$pidnum','$pm_phone','$todaydate')";
        $conn->query($sqlfail);
    }
}
```

Comment: your update code i working now but insert is still not work

Comment: insert might not work because you are getting values by `select` query

Comment: if mysqli_num_rows($result) is zero the else should work and insert ino fail table is right?

Comment: Yes. Insert should wrk

Answer (score 0):

Where is the $conn object come from? try this..

```
<?php

if($_POST["displayid"])
{

$sqlid = "SELECT * FROM doc1 WHERE idnum ='$pidnum' AND stats='$ok'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlid);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

   $sqlup= "UPDATE doc1 SET  m_phone='$pm_phone' AND seen='$dataseen' WHERE  idnum ='$pidnum'";
   mysqli_query($conn, $sqlup);

   $found=1;

}
else
{

$found=0;

$sqlfail="INSERT INTO fail(fname,lname,tname,funame,idnum,m_phone,reg_date)
VALUES('$pfname','$plname','$ptname','$pfuname','$pidnum','$pm_phone','$todaydate')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sqlfail);


}

}
```

Comment: in the upadte code error was using ", " instant of "AND" - but insert code not working